# Angular js National identity card Number Validation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I created directive for validate nic no as follows

```
CustomerCompanyApp.directive('nicOnly', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, modelCtrl) {
            var limit = parseInt(attrs.nicOnly);
            elem.bind('keypress', function (e) {

                //console.log(e.charCode);
                if (elem[0].value.length >= limit) {
                    if (e.charCode != 0) {
                        //console.log(e.charCode);
                        e.preventDefault();
                        return false;
                    }

                } else {
                    if (elem[0].value.length == limit - 1) {

                        modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (inputValue) {
                            var transformedInput = inputValue ? inputValue.replace(/^[X|x|V|v]$/, '') : null;

                            if (transformedInput != inputValue) {
                                modelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
                                modelCtrl.$render();
                            }

                            return transformedInput;
                        });


                    } else {
                        modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (inputValue) {
                            var transformedInput = inputValue ? inputValue.replace(/[^\d]/g, '') : null;

                            if (transformedInput != inputValue) {
                                modelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
                                modelCtrl.$render();
                            }

                            return transformedInput;
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

In chtml

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="customerNicNoforconfirmation">National identity card no</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="customerNicNoforconfirmation" id="customerNicNoforconfirmation1" ng-model="customerNicNoforconfirmation" required="" nic-only="10">
                <p ng-show="NicDetailsform.customerNicNoforconfirmation.$invalid && !NicDetailsform.customerNicNoforconfirmation.$pristine" class="danger">Customer Nic Required.</p>
            </div>
```

**In above directive can limit the length and input only numeric**. 
but now i want to add this validation in to my directive,

1. First 9 character of the input must be numeric.
2. Last 1 character of the input must V v X x Letter.
3. Length of the whole input must be 10

in my directive it can limit whole input length to 10 and all inputs are only numeric. i couldn't find way to overcome other requirements.

Answer (score 0):

i couldn't find way to solve this using directive
finally i found ng-pattern to solve my problem

```
<div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="customerNicNoforconfirmation">National identity card no</label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="customerNicNoforconfirmation" id="customerNicNoforconfirmation" ng-model="customerNicNoforconfirmation" required="" ng-pattern="/^\d{9}[V|v|X|x]$/" limit-to="10">
                            <p ng-show="NicDetailsform.customerNicNoforconfirmation.$dirty && NicDetailsform.customerNicNoforconfirmation.$error.pattern" class="danger">First 9 characters must be numbers and last character must be V or X letter </p>
                        </div>
```

**ng-pattern="/^\d{9}[V|v|X|x]$/"**